# Executing the tasks with sudo privileges in ansible playbook

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sudo, ansible, privilege-elevation

I have simple ansible playbook

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: myusername
  become: yes
  become_user: myusername
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: Install tmux
      apt: name=tmux state=present
```

I get the below error while running the playbook.

```
TASK: [Install tmux] ********************************************************** 
failed: [104.239.140.237] => {"failed": true}
stderr: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I referred to http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html to escalate the privileges of the user.

The user 'myusername' belongs to sudo group.

```
$ sudo -l -U myusername
User myusername may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

I am able to successfully install the tmux using the below command on console. Not really sure what I am missing while doing the same inside the playbook.

```
$ sudo apt-get install tmux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

Comment: I take it that the host where you ran `sudo -l -U myusername` is the remote ansible target and not the one you are running `ansible-playbook` on? Or is it all the same host?

Comment: Its the remote node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check or modify the sudoers file for `NOPASSWD`, your playbook works for me and the only difference I see is:

```
User myusername may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This is as much as confirmed by Ansible docs, which state:

```
–become,-b
run operations with become (no password implied)
```

If you can't change the server-side config for this, you can still use the `sudo` directive.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html